# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server - opencv::imshow() causes ": cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0"

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, imshow

So I am trying to run my code on an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

I realized that my code is breaking with the following error when imshow() is called:

```
: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

I an connecting through putty and I have selected "Enable X11 Forwarding".

I can remove all imshow calls but I actually need to use them. Is there a way to enable this functionality while connecting to the EC2 instance through Putty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to be running an X windows server on your desktop (where you're running putty).  There are several available, and setup depends on which you choose.  If you want a very easy solution, there's [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), which is an ssh client and X11 server combined.  There's a commercial version and a free home edition (with some limitations).

Comment: MobaXterm proved to be such a great tool ! Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.