# cv imshow throwing error

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I'm running the below code in python

```
import numpy as np import cv2

print "hello"

img = cv2.imread('image.JPG',0) print img

cv2.imshow('sood',img)
```

I'm getting the below error every time - Can someone help!

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file
>   /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
>   line 583 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "cv2ImageProcessing.py", line 9, in 
>       cv2.imshow('sood',img) cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583:
>   error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with
>   Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian,
>   install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure
>   script in function cvShowImage

Comment: I'm getting an array printed when I print "img", so image is getting probably read, but imshow is still not working.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS SO PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207011/opencv-not-working-properly-with-python-on-linux-with-anaconda-getting-error-th?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install `libgtk2.0-dev` it seems like it is asking you to install that. Try `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`.

If it doesn't work out then try installing all the dependencies mentioned in the [script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh). I installed OpenCV on my system using this script and everything works fine.

Comment: libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config and GTK all of them are already installed and I verified again just now, but still seems to be giving the same error
Help!

Comment: Did you check the script? Just run it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

This script works:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

print "hello"

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
print img

cv2.imshow('sood',img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Most likely your OpenCV3 is not properly installed. Try to reinstall it. Read [this how-to](https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-python-windows/). It is very easy to install Python OpenCV3 on Windows with [*.whl file](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv).