# OpenCV python get error when use imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to `openCV` and installed it from [this](http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/) link and it compiled and installed with no error. after that when i open an ipython and run these commands:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# create an image matrix using nimpy called img
cv2.imshow("image", img)
```

I get this error message:

```
/io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

I do what said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40864098/5201134) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14656610/5201134) links but my problem didn't solve.

Comment: your tutorial link is broken

Comment: @eshirima I edited the link, I remove all openCV packages and install it from `anaconda` but still the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not working, so I can't be more specific. But what's happening is that your self-compiled OpenCV didn't pick up on any necessary development-packages to chose a rendering backend (Qt or whatever it uses).

You should check the cmake output for lines stating what libraries were searched for and not found, and install *-dev packages of the respective libraries.

Comment: I edited the link,  I remove all openCV packages and install it from anaconda but still the problem remains.

Comment: I don't know much about the anaconda build, but the underlying problem needs to be solved - remove the C++ library and re-build it. Please post the output of cmake.

Answer (score 0):

From your error log, you have missed out on a few dependencies while compiling the code.

install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config.

Install these to make sure OpenCV works as it should