# OpenCV 3.1.0 imshow in Linux does not work for webcam (Python)

Tags: python, linux, opencv, anaconda, webcam

I'm trying to use code from the official openCV tutorial for showing video from webcam using `cv2.imshow()` in Ubuntu/Python 3.6:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I get the following error for `cv2.imshow()`:

> The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage

When searching for the error I stumbled upon this post as an alternate answer to similar questions:

> If you installed OpenCV using the opencv-python pip package at any point in time, be aware of the following note, taken from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python
>
> > IMPORTANT NOTE MacOS and Linux wheels have currently some limitations:
> >
> > - video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with FFmpeg)
> > - for example cv2.imshow() will not work (not compiled with GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support)
>
> Also note that to install from another source, first you must remove the opencv-python package

[OpenCV error: the function is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655969/opencv-error-the-function-is-not-implemented)

[OpenCV not working properly with python on Linux with anaconda. Getting error that cv2.imshow() is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207011/opencv-not-working-properly-with-python-on-linux-with-anaconda-getting-error-th)

Most other openCV functions work properly.

Is there an alternative to `cv2.imshow()` that uses standard anaconda libraries so I don't have to recompile openCV or use Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked together a quick and dirty snippet that uses `matplotlib.animation` and resembles what cv2.imshow() is expected to do with webcam video:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
# The following is the replacement for cv2.imshow():
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), animated=True)
def updatefig(*args):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    im.set_array(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    return im
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

I found this very useful, as I was able to output many overlapping plots on top of the webcam video thanks to the fact that `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` can animate as many plots as there are attached to the `ax` object as long as they are updated in the `updatefig()` function above.

Edit: As I was working in a Jupyter notebook, I added the following in order to see the video in a new window:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
```