# conda installs openCV 3.4.2 with caffe but it cannot be removed alone

Tags: python, opencv, conda, package-managers

New python3 environment created with

```
conda create -n py3CVCaffe python=3.7
```

caffe installed with

```
conda install caffe-gpu=1.0=py37hdc87d0a_5
```

among the many packages installed are these two

```
libopencv-3.4.2            |       hb342d67_1        40.4 MB
py-opencv-3.4.2            |   py37hb342d67_1         1.2 MB
```

both packages are installed and seem to be functional

```
$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

However certain video functions are absent as the openCV which is provided has not been compiled

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv-suite_1535558553474/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:632: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

This is a well known problem as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207011/opencv-not-working-properly-with-python-on-linux-with-anaconda-getting-error-th)

So I need to install an openCV that has been compiled with these libraries. Before I do that I have to remove the openCV that was pulled in with caffe.
Unfortunately, conda does not want to-it also wants to remove caffe!

```
$conda uninstall py-opencv
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/p37cu9CfeG

  removed specs:
    - py-opencv


The following packages will be REMOVED:

  caffe-gpu-1.0-py37hdc87d0a_5
  py-opencv-3.4.2-py37hb342d67_1


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove `py-opencv` and not any of its reverse dependencies, then use the `--force` flag.  From the `conda remove --help`:

> --force-remove, --force
>                           Forces removal of a package without removing packages
>                           that depend on it. Using this option will usually
>                           leave your environment in a broken and inconsistent
>                           state.

which should be read as "*do so at your own risk*".