# Unspecified error and the function is not implemented in opencv

Tags: python

python duke.py

> Traceback  (most recent call last):    File "duke.py", line 5, in
>   
>        cv2.imshow('ktm',img)
>
> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2)
>   /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1535678557175/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:632:
>   error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild
>   the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on
>   Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run
>   cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

here is my code

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Downloads/404615.jpg',1)

while True:

    cv2.imshow('ktm',img)

    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0*FF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Solved it by doing the following:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happen because of conda. Follow the commands below and should solve your problem:

```
conda remove opencv
conda install -c menpo opencv
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

There are also other possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207011/opencv-not-working-properly-with-python-on-linux-with-anaconda-getting-error-th)

Comment: when i got your post thought about it's  miscellaneous

Comment: if you know about that you may answer my post

Comment: are you on ubuntu?

Comment: FF is not defined

Comment: Can you see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913241/error-in-executing-opencv-in-ubuntu) and try the solutions there

Answer (score 0):

It back to normal after I try to reinstall the opencv

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling and reinstalling opencv seems to work for some people. Though, if you want to understand want happened, the answer is here;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68975495/4838973